# Reporting Services - user always must logon in browser

Tags: reporting-services

Environment:
Windows Server 2012 R2,MS SQL Server 2014 Standard,Reporting Services. 
Problem is when domain user with sufficient rights open reporting portal in browser - **is always asked for credentials**. We tried to add user to Administrator group, but with no success. Only if browser is opened under domain administrator account, portal opens without asking for credentials. 
Which privilegues/settings are ommited ?

*Edit - new facts:*
1.       Reporting Services are installed in Native mode – I forgot to mentioned it before.
2.       There are some RS/web portal related configuration files, all from following folder “C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer”
·       Web.config
·       Rsreportserver.config

**Answers to discussion**
·       1. All browsers the same behavior
·       2. All folder permissions (for required account “HIMA\scadaserver”) on RS portal folders have been set to following roles : Browser, Content Manager, My Reports, Publisher, Report Builder
Portal Site Settings/Security has been set to “System Administrator”
·       3. No, we are using data sources integrated inside particular reports. It looks that the problem with access to RS portal is not problem of data sources and access to database. The portal HOME folder page requires credentials  – at this time there is no request for data from database. Is this correct?

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers you try? IE, Chrome, Edge, others?

Comment: Have you set user permissions on the folder? At minimum you need to set Browser for each domain user/group on the 'Home' folder on the server (see Manage Folder/Security on the portal). Permissions will be inherited automatically, but you can override that. See here for more information https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156034.aspx

Comment: are you using a shared data source? if not that could be the reason.

Comment: please, some other suggestions according my edit in main thread ?